# Using flags with logical operators instead of conditional statements (Such as if())

Tags: c, optimization, flags, logical-operators

Suppose I want to change the value of a variable when a flag is set. An obvious method is the following.

```
int a = 1, b = 2;
if(Flag)
    {
    a=b;
    Flag = false;
    }
```

This, however, is quite inefficient WRT the code generated to perform the operation. I have found that the following generates 40% less code to perform the operation.

```
a = ((!Flag)*a)+((Flag)*b);
Flag = false;
```

My question: I would rather not use the multiply "*" operator as multiplicative/division operators are slower to execute on my target. What else could I use to speed this up without increasing code space?

**EDIT:** The target device is an MSP430 running in the kHz range. code space and execution time are critical. the compiler is IAR C

Comment: Doesn't `a = ((!Flag)*a)+((Flag)*b);` end up in an unnecessary assignment of `a=a` when `Flag` is `false`? Wouldn't you rather use the conditional to avoid that?

Comment: @Mike yes it does, however the code generated is still far less than when using conditionals.

Comment: *::face palm::* Don't. Just, don't. Use a good compiler and let it do the optimization. [It is almost certainly better at it then you are](http://www.linux-kongress.org/2009/slides/compiler_survey_felix_von_leitner.pdf) and people (including your future self) will be able to read your code. Notice the part where is says *"gcc is smarter than the video codec programmer on all platforms."* (page 41)

Comment: @dmckee The compiler is IAR C. I can assure you that this is a very good (and expensive) compiler.

Comment: How about `int b = 2, a = Flag ? b : 1; Flag = false;`?

Comment: @KerrekSB Interesting!! I forgot about ternary operators.. I will have to try that out. Post that as an answer and it might be one of the best ones here.

Comment: Gcc is also available for that platform, and if you have to write ugly code like that to get the performance you need you might want to check if gcc does better.

Comment: FYI ternary operators typically compile down to be pretty much the same code as an if statement.

Comment: 40% less code, maybe, but that 60% contains 2 multiplications. You can't just count instructions and compare.

Comment: @Shahbaz I know this. That is why I posed the question "I would rather not use the multiply "*" operator as multiplicative/division operators are slower to execute on my target. What else could I use to speed this up without increasing code space?"

Comment: @Jeremy You don't need to multiply or use conditionals, see the mask solution I proposed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following achieves your desired logic without using multiply or any conditionals:

```
unsigned int mask = Flag-1;
a = (mask & a) | (~mask & b);
```

So when Flag==1 you get

```
a = (0x0 & a) | (0xffff & b);
```

and when Flag==0 you get

```
a = (0xffff & a) | (0x0 & b);
```

(You don't really need a separate variable for mask either.. you can just do `--Flag` and use `Flag` instead of `mask`, I just thought it'd make the solution a little clearer.)

Comment: my self-enforced rules : don't mix logical and binary arithmetic operators in the same statement. I like this edit...

Comment: @hexist using `ResetTimeout--;
  Timeout = (ResetTimeout & CMD_TIMEOUT_INIT) | (~ResetTimeout & Timeout);
  ResetTimeout = false;` instead of the if statement resulted in a 68% reduction in CODE space.

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler is able to optimize your code better than this *hack* (check generated assembly). Except on such processors where comparaisons are slow (eg PowerPC), you should avoid it. Anyway, see [here](http://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/04/more-techniques-for-eliminating-branches.html) if you still motivated.

Answer (score 1):

I would write it this way, without any thought about micro-optimization:

```
int b = 2, a = Flag ? b : 1;

Flag = false;
```

Have a look how efficient that is.

Comment: This should generate pretty much the same op codes, just in a different order. Otherwise the compiler is poorly configured/bad.

Comment: In my case, changing `a = ((!Flag)*a)+((Flag)*b)` to `a = Flag ? b : a` saved 10 bytes of CODE memory. That's a 58% reduction from the if statement.

Comment: Also, @KerreckSB `a = ((!Flag)*a)+((Flag)*b)` generates only 4 lines of assembly

Answer (score 0):

Your initial code is as effective as it gets. If you are able to generate more effective code with some other obscure obfuscation, your compiler's optimization is either incorrectly configured or badly written. The former is more likely, but in case of the latter, ask IAR why their compiler generates bad code. Don't try to fix their compiler by writing obfuscated code.

You do not need to use the conditional ?: operator, it should generate exactly the same code.

Further, I don't know much about MSP430 but it is an average 16-bitter and it won't have any super-advanced instruction cache or branch prediction, you are only fooling yourself if you think it has. Even if it had, you should still not obfuscate your code.